# Unable to save webp file to model field

Tags: python, django

I'm not sure if this is entirely django related, but if someone could help me, that would be so much appreciated! I'm having trouble generating a webp file from the following code

```
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image
import requests
```

I've got the following model

```
class UserImage(models.Model):     
     user_provided_image = VersatileImageField(upload_to=folder10, null=True, blank=True)     
  nextgen_image = models.FileField(upload_to=folder10,null=True, blank=True) #for WebP images
```

I'm creating a webp file. This code works, but it saved it to the file to the root directory of my project and I'm not sure how to save it to the FileField (i.e. nextgen_image ) on my model

```
def create_webp_image(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):

    image_url = instance.image.thumbnail['1920x1080'].url    

    try:
        response = requests.get(image_url, stream=True)
        path = image_url

    except: #local env
        path = "http://localhost:8000" + image_url
        response = requests.get(path, stream=True)

    img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))

    #build file path
    position = path.rfind("/") + 1
    newpath = path[0:position]
        
    #build file name
    image_name = path[position:]
    name_of_file = image_name.split('.')[0] + ".webp"
       
    #this creates the webp file
    img.save(name_of_file,"webp")

    #save image to model
    #instance.nextgen_image = ?

post_save.connect(create_webp_image, sender=UserImage)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use packages to get the job done then use this package [django-resized](https://pypi.org/project/django-resized/).

Based on the code provided above this should do the trick. Hoping that this will solve your issue. Cheers

```
nextgen_image = ResizedImageField(force_format="WEBP", 
upload_to=folder10,null=True, blank=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like that:

```
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile

...
img_content = ContentFile(BytesIO(response.content))
instance.nextgen_image.save(name_of_file, img_content, save=True)
...
```